# Move Sharepoint 2010 and SQL from one server to 2 different servers

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, web-services, migration, sql-server, backup

I am moving a server that has Sharepoint 2010 Standard and SQL 2008 R2 installed to 2 different servers.
Could someone explain in detail, what are the steps to achieve this?
What are the things that need to be careful when moving the server?

I have seen that I need to be careful with the owners of service applications and else but isn't there any dynamic way to achieve a server with exactly same configuration?

Thanks

Comment: Is the new server that's going to be SQL server better than the old server?

Comment: Yes
Currently SQL and sharepoint is on same server
By separating them on different machines, hope it gives some better performance.

Comment: It'll give better performance, but what I asked was if the specs of the new Server for SQL is better than for the currently shared one. If not then you might just add a new Server to the farm as SharePoint Server, move all services and then remove the SharePoint part from the old server.